# East/West communication in a AWS serverless microservice architecture

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture

I am well aware of the fact that east/west, or service to service synchronous communication between services is not the gold standard, and should only be used sparingly in a microservice architecture. However, in every real world implementation of a microservice architecture, I have seen some use-cases which require it. For example, the user service is often needs to be communicated with by other services to get up the millisecond details on the user (I'm aware that event based sharing of that data is also a possibility, but in some cases that isn't always the right approach).

My question is, what is the best way to do function to function, service to service communication in a Lambda + API Gateway style architecture?

My guess is that making an http request back out on the domain name is not ideal, since it will require going back out over the internet to resolve DNS.

Is it using the SDK to do an invoke on the downstream function directly? Will this cause issue if the downstream function depends on an API Gateway Proxy Event structure?

Comment: Actually if you want to skip the async communications between your services, why don`t move to another architectural approached ?

Comment: @Luillyfe how is that helpful to this question?